# when injecting dll how does the user program execute it

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

if you wanted to execute the whole code in a dll through a user process how would you do it? After createremotethread is used to execute loadlibraryA from the kernel32.dll and when it loads the dll in user space how does the exe then execute all the code within it?

Comment: Please use google for basic questions like this.  Query "createremotethread dll injection" and you'll find lots of very good hits that demonstrate the technique.  And please stop asking the same question repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that LoadLibrary() does nothing but loading the DLL's code into the virtual memory space of the process that called LoadLibrary().

This means: LoadLibrary() is some kind of malloc() that allocates some memory and then loads the content of the DLL into the memory. At this point no code of the DLL is executed, yet.

Typically a DLL contains a lot of functions. None of these functions is executed.

However a DLL has an "initialization code". This code is executed by LoadLibrary(). This "initialization code" is the code that is used by people who want to inject code into other processes.

The following article describes three techniques to inject code into other processes:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces

If you do not understand that article (this is how I understand Hans Passant's comment) you are missing some basic knowledge about DLLs and processes and you will not understand code injection.